# Equivalent Current in Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, circuit-theory, superposition

I have the following circuit:

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the equivalent current.  In my approach resistors 2 and 1 are in parallel so their equivalent resistance would be 2/3 then since resistors 1 and 2/3 are in series I will get an equivalent resistance of 5/3

[image]

Now since the 2 resistances are in parallel I get the equivalent resistance as 1.06. Now the current in the circuit is \$V/R\$ so \$1/1.06=0.94\$. But the answer in the textbook says it's 0.66. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

The left 1ohm resistor does not affect the circuit at all, you might as well remove it.

Then the remaining 1ohm and 2ohm resistors are in series making them effectively a single 3ohm resistor.

Then the two 3ohm resistors are in parallel, giving a single 1.5ohm resistor.

And finally 1V/1.5ohm is 0.67A.

Comment: Thanks..but what if i dont remove it? There is no rule that says i should remove it,right?

Comment: You can also think about the open circuit as a resistor of infinite resistance. Then it is in series with the leftmost 1ohm resistor and together they form a single infinite-resistance resistor. Which in parallel with the other 1ohm resistor forms a 1ohm resistor.

Comment: Basically that resistor just dangling off in space, so it doesn't have a path for current to flow through it. (As avakar said, the resistance between those open terminals is infinite.) Now, if something were connected to the circuit between those terminals, things would be different!

Comment: @JohnSpeeks Well then if you think like that the final resistance 1.5ohm will be left in space so we can ignore it??

Comment: No, the final resistance forms a complete circuit. You can draw a path starting at the voltage source, through any of the other resistors, and back to the voltage source again. Not so for the dangling one!

Comment: @JohnSpeeks But the final circuit still remains open...

Comment: No it doesn't. It's a complete circuit through the other resistors. Just because someone drew extra dangling lines, components, and circles off the edges of the circuit doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks This will be the final circuit with equivalent resistance right http://imgur.com/aXesunT ?

Comment: No. No idea how you got that. Start again. First, by removing the dangling lines and components.

Comment: Your circuit WOULD be right if you closed it and didn't have a random gap in it, by the way.

Comment: @avakar How do you say that after removal of the 1 ohm resistor, 2 and 1 are in series? Arent they // as the current will split up into 2? What is the logic you have applied.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks This is the problem im trying to solve.. they are open circuiting the current source.http://imgur.com/dcZf0Hi

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8LcVP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
$$I_s = I_1 + I_2$$
$$I_2 = \frac{V_1}{R_1} = \frac{1}{3}A$$
$$I_1 = \frac{V_1}{(R_2+R_3)} = \frac{1}{(2+1)}A = \frac{1}{3}A$$
$$I_s = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}A$$
The R4 does not contribute anything as it has no path.

Comment: Thanks... Since 1 ohm does not contribute to anything if we remove 1ohm  and see the resultant circuit,why we say that 1ohm and 2 ohm are in series and the resulting resistor and the 3 ohm is in parallel.

Comment: Exactly, and most important is that this is a current divider.

Comment: How is this circuit reduction possible http://imgur.com/x4QiEih ? Isnt 2 ohm and 3 ohm in series?

Comment: Because the 3ohm is shorted out or bypassed by the wire in parallel, btw don't forget to vote me up if you like my answers.

Comment: one more question please.. To use current division the incoming current should not have a resistor in between right ?But in this case http://imgur.com/x4QiEih 1A first passes through 1 ohm resistor before entering the //circuit.

Comment: That particular circuit has a current source with a series resistor, but there is still 1A flowing through the resistor into the centre node. The voltage at the node will be total current * total resistance which is 1/(1.5) = 2/3ohm. Thus voltage at the node is 2/3V. Then you can determine the current in each path.